# Prometheus Alertmanager HA config in config file

Tags: prometheus

In the documentation I see you can provide flags to specify the high availability information: https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager#high-availability

How do I specify these things in the config file instead of as CLI params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These can only be specified on the command line.

In general in Prometheus, a setting is either in the config or on the command line - never both.

Comment: I see.  Is this going to be moved into the config file at some point so I can more easily iterate the list of servers or use some sort of service discovery?

Comment: That is not currently on the cards for this setting.